# How to print ArrayList value when it is in private member of any class

Tags: java, arraylist

I have deal with one problem while accessing `arraylist` element in another class. I have 2 classes: class A and class B.

```
class A {
    private ArrayList<String> temp=new ArrayList<String>();
    temp.add("abc");
    temp.add("XYZ");
    public ArrayList<String> getTemp() {
        return this.temp;
    }
}

public class B
{   
    private A a=null;   
    public b(A aa)
    {
        this.a = aa;
    }
    System.out.printLn(a.getTemp.size());//output is 2
    System.out.printLn(a.getTemp.get(0));//null
}
```

Why it is giving me null? Please give brief explanation of this.

Comment: Your code has a hell lot of errors. *(Code outside of any method, constructor name not matching the class's..)*

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working version of what you are trying to achieve:

**A.java**

In the `A` class, you should be adding elements to your `ArrayList` in the constructor:

```
public class A {
    private ArrayList<String> temp=new ArrayList<String>();

    public A() {
        temp.add("abc");
        temp.add("XYZ");
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getTemp() {
        return this.temp;
    }
}
```

**B.java**

The **constructor** name should match the class's:

```
public class B {
    private A a=null;

    public B(A aa)
    {
        this.a = aa;
    }
}
```

**App.java**

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        System.out.println(a.getTemp().size());
        System.out.println(a.getTemp().get(0));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2
abc
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current code won't even compile.

Furthermore, I can guarantee 100% that if by some magic your code were to compile the output of the first `printLn` would in no way be `2`. It would be `null`. `

Answer (score 1):

```
     **First Of All Your Code Is Not Impossible to run**
     You Can't assign value to instance variable directly in side of class without constructor or method so your modified class A must be like   
    **A.java**
     class A {
              private ArrayList<String> temp=new ArrayList<String>();

              public A()
              {
                       temp.add("abc");
                       temp.add("XYZ");
              }

              public ArrayList<String> getTemp() 
              {
                       return this.temp;
              }
     }

              OR Like

     class A {
              private ArrayList<String> temp=new ArrayList<String>();

              public A()
              {
                     initialize();
              }

              public void initialize()
              {
                       temp.add("abc");
                       temp.add("XYZ");
              }


              public ArrayList<String> getTemp() 
              {
                       return this.temp;
              }
     }

    And Then As per Above Your Class B will Be
    **B.java**
    class B
            {   
                    private A a=null;   

                    public B(A aa)
                    {
                        this.a = aa;
                    }

            }

   And Then you have to go for main method like

   **Temp.java**
   public class Temp {
                        public static void main(String... args)
                        {
                            A a = new A();
                            B b = new B(a);



                            System.out.println(a.getTemp().size());//output is 2
                            System.out.println(a.getTemp().get(0));//abc
}
```

}